Alternatives to spray foam (or Gapotape) around foam board insulation?
I'm doing a cut and cobble insulation job in the roof of a 12'x16' Tuff Shed. The rafters are 2x4 and the spacing of each bay varies because of installation plus warping/twisting. I'm using 2.5" felt-faced polyiso insulation to allow a 1" air gap between the radiant barrier roof decking and the insulation (I've added appropriate soffit and ridge vents to ventilate that space).
The climate is classified as predominantly warm and dry (climate zone 3B), though this doesn't tell the full story because the temperature and humidity vary widely in the West Texas panhandle not only seasonally, but also daily and weekly depending on the intersection of regional weather patterns.
My question is about sealing the inevitable gaps between the polyiso pieces and the rafters. I know spray foam is often used for this, but not only is it difficult to apply upward, it will eventually crack and fail in this climate. I would use Gapotape but it is expensive and not yet easily available in the US.
As an alternative, I'm thinking to use rolls of sill gasket foam (e.g., Propink ComfortSeal) and just staple that up to help friction fit and seal around the edges of the polyiso. If I use a 5.5" wide sill gasket folded in half, it will fit nicely inside the rafters and nominally give me up to 3/8" of compressible foam on either side of the rigid foam board.
Do you foresee any problems with such an approach? If so, what other options are there?
Here is a photo of what I have in mind (2.5" rigid foam board will then go in flush with the bottom of the rafters leaving a 1" ventilated gap along the bottom of the reflective roof material):



Maybe you are taking about a different product, but I used canned spray foam for gap sealing in my insulation project (also with foam board panels), and it's very easy and quick to apply. Just wear gloves to avoid getting it on your hands. I can't speak to the cracking question. If you're gaps aren't too large for the product rating, I would not expect failure any time soon. Might be more of a problem if the structural components of the building are moving significantly - but that would be a problem for most things

I agree with blarg. Spray foam is sticky as heck, and I have never seen it crack without there being some other unusual action involved.

Thanks guys, but I'd like to avoid the canned spray foam for a number of reasons:

it will eventually dry up and become brittle (roof gets very hot in summer)
both daily and seasonal heating and cooling will surely create movement in the rafters
it's messy and hard to apply upwards


Should I delete this and repost it? It was closed and I revised it over a week ago, but nobody seems able to review and consider reopening it. I understand this site is for "contractors and serious DIYer" - maybe I'm not being serious enough?

Looks good to me! I tweaked the second to last paragraph to hopefully sound a bit more not looking for opinions. Vote to reopen.

The main advantage with Gapotape is the speed of installation. If that isn't so critical, what you suggest sounds OK.  It's more work to install but that's the tradeoff.  Also Gapotape may be more tolerant if the board doesn't match the space accurately - many joists aren't exactly parallel. (Question seems fine to me, but I don't have a vote on reopening)
